# how to extract embedded images in email body using java

Tags: jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I can see many ways to embed images into email but not extracting the embedded image from email body content using java. I'm able to extract the text content in email body but the embedded images is shown with  tags and with a CID (component ID). I need to extract it and store as an attachment into DB. I think it should be done like calling the server to extract the content and I'm not sure of it. Please help me to get this done. Your help on this is highly appreciated.

I can see something like this in email headers for an image,

[cid:image002.jpg@01CE978E.097473A0]

Answer (score 0):

Extracting an image is like extracting the content for any other body part.  Find the correct MimeBodyPart and use the getInputStream method to read the bytes or use the saveFile method to save the contents to a file.

If that's not working for you, explain in more detail what you've tried and what happened.  See also the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html) for [debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).